# Saving HTML text permanently in map tip display text

Tags: qgis, html

I have used the map display text in QGIS to add HTML which enables me to view images related to a point feature when i hover the mouse over it.

However I have realized that I have to rewrite the code each time I reopen the layer.

Is it possible to save it in such a way that it is permanently saved in the layer properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ahmadhanb's answer is close, but if you click the "Save as Default" option from the Style dropdown menu in the layer properties than the style (including the map tip) will automatically be loaded whenever you open this layer in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the map tip as a ".qml" file same as if you are saving a style, as you can see below:

[image]

You need to go to Style => Save Style => QGIS Layer Style File

Then when you want to load the ".qml" file, go to Style => Load Style